# Accessing NTFS files on ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10, ntfs

I have a dual boot setup with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 on my Asus K401UQ notebook. I have the following partitions

1. C:/ Drive (OS partition) (NTFS)
2. Two data partitions, formatted as NTFS. D:/ and E:/
3. Ubuntu - ext4 partition, for OS and Data together.
4. Swap Space for Ubuntu
5. Miscellaneous recovery and system partitions for windows

I find that it is only possible to write files to the Data partitions if fast boot is turned off in Windows. Is it possible to access only the data partitions in windows from Ubuntu ( with write access), even with fast boot on? I have a feeling this might be possible because fast boot is just storing system files, related to booting the OS.

Comment: If you feel fast boot is just storing system files related, then why not simply leave it disabled? What I understand is that, when turned off, your Windows still boots ok and your Ubuntu can access the NTFS partitions as you want. So why look further is my feeling...

Comment: fast boot on w10 is sorta like a hibernate; it has a system image it restores as a means to fast-boot (re-built when needed such as system updates); plus it leaves the file system open - causing other OSes (ubuntu in your case) reading the fs that it detects is in an 'unsafe' condition (thus refuses write access).  this condition w10 doesn't see as a problem, as its no problem when w10 is the only OS on the machine.   it's a design issue b/c of how 'fast-boot' was written.

Comment: Fastboot, as the name suggests, makes my system boot faster, an I would certainly like it if windows could boot fast. I was of the impression that there would be a way wherein windows stores an image of the system files, and not files in other data partitions, thereby allowing access to other OS's. Looking at @guiverc 's reply about how it keeps the filesystem open, perhaps this is not possible!

Answer (score 3):

**You can't if fast boot is in use!**

As @guiverc has pointed out, its not a full and normal poweroff when you are using fastboot.

Well it's for your own good(your data's own health) ubuntu refuses to write. Who knows if you 'find a way' some way some how(I dunno how), your files might end up corrupt(or may be marked as corrupt on windows)!